# Codeigniter menus/pages, best practices

Tags: php

am wondering what the best practices are re: creating menus and pages via code igniter.

I'm not clear on what best practices would be re: creating menus and pages via code igniter.

currently what I have is this…

one controller with several diff functions. each function is a corresponding page and loads a corresponding view. my concern is in the menu I'm having to use things like…

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/home/products">Products</a>
```

and am using header and footer includes which, if displaying an image do this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>img/logo-small.gif" alt="Floyd Eats Little Logo">
```

my concern is,.. is that too many function calls?, site_url() and base_url() ??

if there is a better way or better practice I'd like to know what it is,

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing anything crazy with your menu, you can simple do something like this in your template.

```
<a href="#" class='<?=($this->uri->segment(3)=="index")?"active":"nonactive"?>'>Index</a> 
<a href="#" class='<?=($this->uri->segment(3)=="about")?"active":"nonactive"?>'>About</a> 
<a href="#" class='<?=($this->uri->segment(3)=="contact")?"active":"nonactive"?>'>Contact</a>
```

If you want to get fancy, you can always use a library like [Library Menu for CodeIgniter](http://twitcode.org/show/267/library-menu-for-codeigniter) to handle your menus.

With regards to your concern about too many function calls, it should not be a huge issue calling `site_url()` many times to create your menu. You can also use the URL helper to create your menu links. The preferred way is to use the URL helper.

```
<?php echo anchor('controller/function/uri', 'Link', 'class="link-class"') ?>
```